# CSS animation swaying curtains

Tags: css, animation

I have a customer who would like curtains opening on his Entrance page, but they can NOT be a Flash animation, and an animated gif is too large in file size. So I created a set of curtains that open with CSS animation on mouseover.
The basic animation is here http://www.nightwingsgraphics.com/Curtains/CurtainsTEST.html

However, since they look more like doors (too stiff) when they open, I added a slight swaying motion here  http://www.nightwingsgraphics.com/Curtains/SwayTEST.html
  Somewhat better, but still too stiff, and I'm lost as to where or how I could add some kind of "warping" (or morphing) effect to make them look more natural.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I also created a jsfiddle for both versions, but it's not allowing me to post more than 2 links here :(

Comment: Well, I thought my post did "include the desired behavior" (add a warping or morphing effect to the curtains to make the opening motion look more natural) and a "specific problem" (where or how to add this effect), but apparently I wasn't clear enough. :(

Comment: **animated curtains**: https://codepen.io/TimLamber/pen/jEmEaP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `skew()` transformation like this

```
#axis:hover .move-right{
    transform: translate(215px,0) scaleX(0.2) skew(-15deg, 5deg);
}

#axis:hover .move-left{
    transform: translate(-215px,0) scaleX(0.2) skew(15deg, -5deg);
}
```

Also see that I chenge the `translate` value because it came out of the container when applying `skew()` function

play with `cubic-bezier` function to improve the transition

```
.object {
   transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.42,0.1,0.44,0.95);    
}
```

I recommend you this page to play with http://cubic-bezier.com/

Also look at the answer to my question here: [How to add physics to CSS animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678792/how-to-add-physics-to-css-animations)

I hope this at least guide you.

PD:I omitted the `vendor-prefixed`  to shorten code

Comment: This is definitely a great start to help point me in the right direction. Much appreciated! Thank you!